# Raspberry Pi V4L2 Compile Error How to Fix

Tags: makefile, raspberry-pi, v4l2

I am using opencv with python on raspberry pi so according to tutorials on the internet I need the V4L2 driver. I'm following this tutorial to install the driver https://www.ics.com/blog/raspberry-pi-camera-module#.VAaCHqM0_YQ

However when I compile I get this error. I don't know what's the problem and have never ran into this problem before. How do I fix this. Thanks.

```
make[3]: Entering directory '/home/pi/v4l-utils/utils/v4l2-compliance'
  CXX    v4l2-test-input-output.o
v4l2-test-input-output.cpp: In function ‘int checkInput(node*, const v4l2_input&, unsigned int)’:
v4l2-test-input-output.cpp:368:3: error: expected primary-expression before ‘.’ token
v4l2-test-input-output.cpp:369:3: error: expected primary-expression before ‘.’ token
v4l2-test-input-output.cpp: In function ‘int checkOutput(node*, const v4l2_output&, unsigned int)’:
v4l2-test-input-output.cpp:733:3: error: expected primary-expression before ‘.’ token
v4l2-test-input-output.cpp:734:3: error: expected primary-expression before ‘.’ token
Makefile:438: recipe for target 'v4l2-test-input-output.o' failed
make[3]: *** [v4l2-test-input-output.o] Error 1
make[3]: Leaving directory '/home/pi/v4l-utils/utils/v4l2-compliance'
Makefile:373: recipe for target 'all-recursive' failed
make[2]: *** [all-recursive] Error 1
make[2]: Leaving directory '/home/pi/v4l-utils/utils'
Makefile:470: recipe for target 'all-recursive' failed
make[1]: *** [all-recursive] Error 1
make[1]: Leaving directory '/home/pi/v4l-utils'
Makefile:398: recipe for target 'all' failed
make: *** [all] Error 2
```

Answer (score 1):

The line numbers have changed somewhat in the 2+ years since this question was posted. It could have easily had more bugs back then with Raspbian 7 Wheezy on a Raspberry Pi 2 or classic Pi.

One correction to the webpage would be that it's better to run `./bootstrap.sh` rather than `autoreconf`. I also write `libjpeg-dev` to avoid dependency problems with the too-specific `libjpeg62-dev`. Then the build and installation works fine today on Raspbian 9 Stretch (gcc 6.3):

```
sudo apt-get install autoconf gettext libtool libjpeg-dev
git clone git://git.linuxtv.org/v4l-utils.git
cd v4l-utils
./bootstrap.sh
./configure
make
sudo make install
```